# Is it correct to say "he has Covid 19" and "he is getting Covid 19" to express currently he is experiencing that illness?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice, present-continuous

The dictionary says

> **[get](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get)** [transitive, no passive] get something to start to develop an illness; to suffer from a pain, etc.
>
> *I think I'm getting a cold.*

---

> **[have something](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/have_1?q=have)** (**not used in the progressive tenses**): to suffer from an illness or a disease
>
> He found out that he had HIV just last year.

Covid 19 is attacking a man **right now**.

Is it correct to say "**he has Covid 19**" and "**he is getting Covid 19**" to express currently he is experiencing that illness?

This is because "**has**" can not in in continuous tenses while "**get**" can.

Comment: "I think I'm getting a cold" means "I am feeling the early symptoms which tell me that I am probably going to have a cold". When the infection is fully developed, you say "I have/I've got a cold."

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly as your dictionary says

"He has Covid19" = He is currently infected and experiencing the illness.

"He is getting Covid19" = He is just starting to develop the symptoms of the illness.

So you might say  "I've had a cough for the last hour. I don't have a fever but, I'm afraid that I might be getting Covid. So I'm going to self-isolate and book a test".

Or "My test came back positive, so it's confirmed. I have Covid. I won't be able to leave my house for the next 10 days."